# Rails act_as_list custom scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list

So I have a simple tasklist where tasks act as list in the :tasklist scope.
Now each task can be marked as archived and goes out from the list.

So i need the act_as_list scope to include the WHERE archived = FALSE condition.

I found this post: http://macdiggs.com/2007/08/27/customizing-scope-in-acts_as_list/ but it's from 2007 and doesn't work for me.
Also I'm using postgres, so I don't want to hardcode archived = false, since postgres handles booleans differently from mysql (i think).

I tried:

```
scope :not_archived, -> { where(archived: false) }
scope :siblings, -> { where(tasklist_id: self.tasklist_id) }
acts_as_list :scope => siblings.not_archived
```

But it doesn't work. The self variable references the Class and not the instance.
I'm a bit lost. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`scope` acts as a class method and `self` within it will reference to Class. Internally Active Record converts a scope into a class method.  You can pass tasklist_id as option

change the siblings scope to

```
scope :siblings, ->(tasklist_id) { where(tasklist_id: tasklist_id) }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Now I get an error "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)". I guess the last line: siblings.not_archived is expecting an argument for the siblings scope: like siblings(5) for instance.